# Reducing the vertical space and changing alignment in a table with '\multicolumn'

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I have this table :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\def\CHECK{\ding{52}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{My table}
        \rowcolors{5}{}{gray!10}
        \begin{tabular}{*8c}
            \toprule
            & Experimentally & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Type} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
              A & Tested     & N  & M & F & O & C\\    
            \midrule
            1 &        & \CHECK &       & \CHECK   \\
            2 &  \CHECK      & \CHECK       & \CHECK  & \CHECK  & \CHECK & \CHECK\\
            3 &        & \CHECK & \CHECK  & \CHECK & \CHECK  & \CHECK \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

which outputs:

[image]

I would like to achieve the following:

1. The word "Type" to be aligned in the center of the line (above M, N, F)
2. I also want the text "Experimentally Tested" to have less vertical space in between. I tried `\vspace{}` and got an error. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Right now, the table doesn't look visually nice.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can reduce the vertical spacing somwhat by setting `\araystretch` to <1, but that only removes the `\strut`.  `\def\arraystretch{0.5}`

Answer (score 2):

For the vertical space, a simple `\multirowcell` (from `makecell`) does it. I added the caption package to have a decent spacing between caption and table. As to the alignment in `\multicolumn`, it is enough to consider the right number of columns (3;, not 5):

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{pifont}
\def\CHECK{\ding{52}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{My table}
    \rowcolors{5}{}{gray!10}
    \begin{tabular}{*8c}
        \toprule
        & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Type} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
          A &\multirowcell{-2}{Experimentally\\ Tested} & N & M & F & O & C\\
        \midrule
        1 & & \CHECK & & \CHECK \\
        2 & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK\\
        3 & & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK & \CHECK \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! Very helpful. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\def\CHECK{\ding{52}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{My table}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{*7c}
    \CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{5}{}{gray!10}
    \Body
        \toprule
        & \Block{2-1}{Experimentally\\ Tested} & \Block{1-3}{Type} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
          A & & N  & M & F & O & C\\    
        \midrule
        1 &        & \CHECK &       & \CHECK   \\
        2 &  \CHECK      & \CHECK       & \CHECK  & \CHECK  & \CHECK & \CHECK\\
        3 &        & \CHECK & \CHECK  & \CHECK & \CHECK  & \CHECK \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks very good :)